# I couldn't upgrade my raspberry pi python version from 3.7 to 3.9

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-3.7, python-3.9

Please help me.
i have try out alot of way to get install, upgrade my python3.7 to python3.9 yet it keep shows up error.

sudo apt-get install python3
(Python3 is already the newest version [3.7.3-1])

sudo apt-get upgrade python3
(Python3 is already the newest version [3.7.3-1])

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
(file "/user/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in )
(sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
(....)
(Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/buster)

sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline6-dev libgdbm-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev sqlite3 zip
(after install 2 newly package)
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev
(still back to python3.7)

anyone know how to make it to python3.9?

Answer (score 1):

you have to type this in terminal:

```
sudo apt install python3.9
```

but you never can upgrade your Linux python to a newer version. It is internal.
but you can install python3.9 and use virtualenv to use your code in python3.9

Comment: Thanks alot, i able to install and use it for python 3.9

Comment: @GermaineOng Please mark the answer as answer so that It will be helpful for others too.